# Is it possible to have UITabBarItem not having an image space on it?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I know it is optional to add an image on the UITabBarItem but in all cases, the text appears at the bottom of the Button in an ugly way.

So, my question is, is there a way to centralize the text **vertically** on the UITabBarItem ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this directly. You can implement a work around by making an image that contains only the text you wish to display and using that as the image for the tab.

Comment: Note: using an image for text is likely to make internationalization difficult.

Comment: Even If I subclassed the UITabBar class?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the image of the text at runtime and add it to the `tabBarItem`'s `image`

This will solve the I18N issue too.

Check out this link

[Rob's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249293/900377)