# Display only text without image for UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to display only title for tabbar item without image. Is it possible? When I tried setting

```
let tabItem = UITabBarItem()
tabItem.title = "Tab1"
tabItem.selectedImage = nil
tabItem.image = nil
tabViewController?.tabBarItem = tabItem
```

I'm just getting a blank space which is tapable, but no title or image.

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248457/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-images-in-the-uitabbaritem-and-aligned-vertically-t) can help u

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simplest way is remove the images from the tab bar and set the custom offset vertical.as shown in the image. or else follow the link that TJ3n priveded [remove the images in the UITabBarItem and aligned vertically the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248457/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-images-in-the-uitabbaritem-and-aligned-vertically-t).

[image]

Comment: Why -16? Where this value come from?

Comment: @ReyBruno -16 is needed to center text vertically. By default it is situated at the lower part of the bar even if you are not setting the image.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want it to be done programmatically:

```
tabItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -16)
```