# Can i only display text in tab bar item and change the style and position

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem, uitabview

I add a tab bar in storyboard, and do not want to set an image to the tab bar item, and like the following:

[image]

How can I change the font and the position for the title of the bar item in storybord?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First select the tab bar item in storyboard, than in Attributes Inspector set System Item and Title Position to Custom, so you will be able to change the position of the title by setting values to Horizontal and Vertical boxes.

[image]

Finally, to change the font, in your `viewDidLoad()`, include:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-BlackOblique", size:20)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue], for: .normal)
```

`NSFontAttributeName` allow you to change the font style and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` allow you to change the font color.

Comment: what about the image it self, i try to adjust it by using the image inset